# External js file problems

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have an external js file with some simple functions. They work fine when in the aspx page. When they are in the external js file, I get an error on the dev machine that the function is not defined. After playing with this for two days in IE9, I tried it in FF and it worked fine. Then, it worked in IE9 too. I had a second site with the same problem. I checked it again and it didn't work in IE9, then checked it in FF, it worked, and then it continued to work in IE9. What could possible cause this?

Comment: How can I test that/fix that?

Comment: @nlehman Anytime you make a change to the script, hit f5 at least once after the page loads. You can use the "Network" tab in the developer tools of IE9 to make sure that you are getting a new version of the script (Result=200) and not a cached version (Result=304)

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately this depends on whether or not the file is being included in the page correctly via the `<script>` tag. I'd be surprised if one browser can resolve a bad reference and another one cannot, since it's ultimately the server's job to determine if a file path is correct or not. So check that your include mechanism is always including the file correctly. You can run a trace with Fiddler for example, and watch for any 404 errors when the browser requests scripts.

The other possibility is that the script itself is being included correctly, but it contains syntax or references that Firefox accepts as valid but IE9 doesn't. For example, a reference to `console` will bomb in some versions of IE but will work fine in Chrome. Check that your script is valid to begin with.

Comment: But why would it work in IE after that? It looks like something is corrupt in my dev machine and gets uncorrupt after testing in FF.

Comment: Are you caching perhaps? Try to turn off all caching and see if that helps.

Comment: How do I do that on my dev machine?

Comment: The easiest way is to stop and start whatever web server you're using, and see if you can reproduce the problem that way.

Comment: I had stopped the web server through the server icon and it continued to happen. I even rebooted in between.

Comment: Did you try running a Fiddler trace? What did you see?

Comment: I didn't yet. Don't forget, it's working perfectly now. It really seems like a cache issue. I wish I could figure out how to recreate the problem and then I would be able to do more debugging.